# Ham Radio Exam in English in West Europe

Tags: license, europe

Is the Ham Radio License exam conducted in English in any of the western European Countries?

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Hello! Thank you! Thrilled to be here!

Answer (score 5):

The UK is a western European Country - aside from Brexit.

The exams are conducted in English language (multiple choice test).

With the "Full Licence" you will receive the HAREC (Harmonized Amateur Radio Examination Certificate) according CEPT recommendation T/R 61-02.

A person who holds a HAREC issued by a country that participates in recommendation T/R 61-02 may apply for a licence in a lot of other countries on production of that HAREC.

See also: 
https://rsgb.org/main/clubs-training/for-students/
and
https://www.ofcom.org.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0026/82637/amateur_radio_licence_guidance_for_licensees.pdf

Comment: Thank you @dingensfredi I will take a look

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the UK conducts test in English. Ireland does also - https://www.irts.ie/cgi/st.cgi?applying.

In addition you can sometimes sit the US FCC exam in various locations through Europe. This can then be used to apply for a US license. The ARRL lists some/most/all dates: http://www.arrl.org/find-an-amateur-radio-license-exam-session

I am assuming you are a European resident trying to get a local license without speaking the local language. If so then check the rules carefully with regard obtaining a local license before proceeding. The FCC don't issue HAREC certificates and this might complicate matters when applying for a local license. Others will know more on this if Google doesn't help.

Doing the exam in the UK is how I got my German license though so I know that definitely works! Note that, maybe depending on your local country, you probably have to qualify for the full UK license to be able to apply for a local license. That means passing the Foundation, Intermediate and Full exams (and there is a practical assessment as well). I'm not sure about Ireland so maybe its simpler there.

Comment: https://www.us-afu-lizenz.de/index.php/en/german-license says that you can use a US license to apply for a German license, even without HAREC, so maybe you can where you are to.